# Correct way to find 8's complement?

Tags: number-systems

I'm trying to figure out how to find 8's complement, but am unable to do so. Online it shows that we need to subtract each digit from 7 when the number is in it's octal bit. It gives the 7's complement and then we add 1 to it to gets the 8's complement.

However some other sources have been subtracting each digit of the number from 8 directly to get the 8's complement.

What is the right procedure of getting 8's complement?

Comment: I don't know, but in octal how would you do the second method if the number contained a 0?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger the second method probably isn't done in octal, but I'm not sure what base is taken either.

Comment: Are you doing octal? Then, the first approach is right.

Comment: @StinkingBishop i see. Then even if the number isn't in octal I can convert it and then perform first method. Any idea whether the second method is credible or not and what base it works on?

Comment: The 7's and 8's complement only make sense in octal, it is not clear to me why you would do a conversion. If a base $n$ is given then you can apply $n-1$'s complement (subtract every digit from $n-1$) or $n$'s complement (same as $n-1$'s complement incremented by $1$). Note that you can have "8's complement" in base 9, which works *differently* from 8's complement in base 8, which is an unfortunate terminological ambiguity. (Thus, always specify your base first.)

Comment: (I was not very coherent in the previous comment, so to clarify: the *first* approach is how you calculate 8's complement in base 8. The *second* approach is how you calculate 8's complement in base 9. The same name "8's complement" is used for two different things, sadly.)

Comment: It's basically a matter of subtracting from $8^n-1$ versus subtracting from $8^n$

Comment: @StinkingBishop hey thanks for clarifying! Now it makes all the more sense.